How do I generate a sitemap with Yoast on Next.js/Faust.js?
I'm trying to follow the instructions here: https://faustjs.org/guide/how-to-use-sitemaps
I created the file at /pages/sitemap.xml.js exactly as described here but /sitemap.xml and /sitemap_index.xml (Yoast URL) both go to 404:
import { getSitemapProps } from '@faustwp/core';

export default function Sitemap() {}

export function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  return getSitemapProps(ctx, {
    frontendUrl: process.env.FRONTEND_URL,
  });
}

Is there anything being left out here? What configuration could be wrong? I've checked and when the file is reached FRONTEND_URL is definitely defined.
My site is based on this starter: https://github.com/wpengine/atlas-blueprint-portfolio
